# How to pick uniq hash value with one more condition

Tags: ruby

I have:

```
h = [{:a=>"Hello", :b=>false}, {:a=>"Hello", :b=>true}, {:a=>"H1", :b=>false}]
```

I want to get unique values based on key `a`, and the value of `b` should be `true`. I want this result:

```
[{:a=>"Hello", :b=>true}, {:a=>"H1", :b=>false}]
```

If I do:

```
h.uniq {|hash| hash.values_at(:a)}
```

this will fetch the first uniq hash. I get:

```
[{:a=>"Hello", :b=>false}, {:a=>"H1", :b=>false}]
```

Comment: You say the value of b should be true but in your end result not every `:b` is true

Comment: Yes  not every :b is true

Comment: Why is `{:a=>"H1", :b=>false}`, which does not have `true` for `:b`, allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not clear. If you just want the result you described, this will work:

```
h.group_by { |e| e[:a] }
 .map { |k, values| values.find { |e| e[:b] == true } || values.first }
#=> [{:a=>"Hello", :b=>true}, {:a=>"H1", :b=>false}]
```

Comment: Depends on the interpretation of the question (which is not clear at all), but I took it that the `e[:b] == true` condition is relaxed only when there is only one element among the uniqueness. Therefore, I would replace your `values.first` with `(values.first if values.one?)`, and add `.compact` at the end..

Comment: @sawa, probably you're right, it depends on the interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Most effective approach would be probably to `reduce`:

```
h.each_with_object({}) do |h, acc|
  acc[h[:a]] = h if acc[h[:a]].nil? || !acc[h[:a]][:b]
end.values
#⇒ [{:a=>"Hello", :b=>true}, {:a=>"H1", :b=>false}]
```